# What is a Substantial Word™?

Tags: word, pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Substantial Word™**.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

**Note: there is a rule for being on the Substantial list and a rule for being on the Insubstantial list. You must find both.**

| Substantial Words™ | Insubstantial Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| dwindled | terminology |
| flabbergasted | marshmallows |
| tablecloth | mathematician |
| abridged | splittable |
| welcoming | maintain |
| overcast | diminutive |
| hamburger | pseudonym |
| accomplishment | psychotherapists |
| segregation | nowhere |
| breadboard | probably |

Many more Substantial and Insubstantial Words exist and are not listed above. Some English words are neither substantial nor insubstantial and some are both.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Substantial and Insubstantial words are

> those whose letters contain, in order, a word meaning "large" or "small" respectively.

Thus:

> d**wi**n**d**l**e**d            **t**erm**in**olog**y**
>  f**la**bbe**rg**ast**e**d,      mar**s**h**mall**ows
>  **ta**b**l**ec**l**oth,         ma**th**emat**i**cia**n**
>  a**b**r**i**d**g**ed,           sp**litt**ab**le**
>  we**l**c**o**mi**ng**,          **m**a**in**ta**i**n
>  o**v**erc**ast**,           **diminutive**
>  **h**amb**u**r**ge**r,          **p**se**u**do**ny**m
>  **a**cco**mpl**ishm**e**nt,     p**s**yc**ho**the**r**apis**t**s
>  se**gre**g**at**ion,        no**w**h**e**r**e**
>  **br**eadb**oa**r**d**,         pro**bab**l**y**

Credit where due: Stiv

> found PUNY and SHORT where I had the clearly-inferior PONY and CHEAP.

Comment: Nice work Gareth - a great spot :) I think perhaps rot13(CHAL engure guna CBAL naq FUBEG engure guna PURNC. V yvxr ZVAV gubhtu!)

Comment: Great job! rot13(Vg vf vaqrrq ZVAV, CHAL, naq FUBEG. Nyfb, V jnf guvaxvat bs ZVAHGR vafvqr qvzvahgvir, ohg vg vf abg jebat gb hfr qvzvahgvir vgfrys.) (@Stiv)

Comment: Dunno how I managed to miss rot13(CHAL naq FUBEG), other than the general incompetence already mentioned in my answer. Will tweak accordingly.

Comment: Now an interesting challenge would be to find a word which is both substantial and insubstantial...

Comment: rot13(FHOBCGVZNYYL) is both because it rot13(pbagnvaf obgu FZNYY naq GNYY).